# Long enum with bitwise

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, bit-manipulation, flags

I've been facing a problem with my `enum` after getting past the 32nd flag:

```
enum ConditionType_t {
    CONDITION_NONE                          = 0,
    CONDITION_LIGHT                         = 1 << 0,
    CONDITION_INFIGHT                       = 1 << 1,
    CONDITION_MUTED                         = 1 << 2,
    ...
    CONDITION_LUCKY                         = 1 << 32,
}
```

Knowing that `enums` are basically `8bit`, `CONDITION_LUCKY` will be equal to the `CONDITION_NONE`. So I implemented `C++11`'s `enum classes`:

```
enum class ConditionType_t : uint64_t {
    CONDITION_NONE                          = 0,
    CONDITION_LIGHT                         = 1 << 0,
    CONDITION_INFIGHT                       = 1 << 1,
    CONDITION_MUTED                         = 1 << 2,
    ...
    CONDITION_LUCKY                         = 1 << 32,
}
```

Now I get millions of warnings like:

```
warning C4293: '<<' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
```

And errors like:

```
error C2065: 'CONDITION_NONE' : undeclared identifier
```

Apparently, bit shifting doesn't get along with `enum classes`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What makes you think that "`enums` are basically `8bit`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `1 << 32` is undefined behavior. From [expr.shift]:

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand
>   is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

Since `1` is an `int`, it only has 32 bits. Even if this wasn't undefined, you wouldn't get the value you wanted either, since the type of `1 << 32` is `int`, which can't hold a 33-bit value anyway.

You'll need to use an `uint64_t` from the start:

```
enum class ConditionType_t : uint64_t {
    CONDITION_NONE                          = 0,
    CONDITION_LIGHT                         = 1ULL << 0,
    CONDITION_INFIGHT                       = 1ULL << 1,
    CONDITION_MUTED                         = 1ULL << 2,
    ...
    CONDITION_LUCKY                         = 1ULL << 32,
};
```